# Why isn't dlt package visible to azure databricks notebook?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

Am I misunderstanding something? Isn't dlt package supposed to be natively available?

I'm getting this error: [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlt'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INImW.png)

I followed this doc but it seems useless as a starting guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta-live-tables/tutorial-python

Looked for other articles and nothing helpful mentioned since the UI seems to have changed:
https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/is-there-some-form-of-enablement-required-to-use-delta-live/m-p/22199#M15186

I tried what's available from the docs. I created the pipeline(no option to include libraries), attached the notebook, but it still can't test my code.

Comment: you can not use the dlt  in the interactive notebook. you need to use that notebook in pipeline. So what is the blockers you are facing when run the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an interactive notebook? check if this solves your problem:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1008642/cant-import-dlt-into-python-notebook

Comment: Thanks for the response. Seems like this can only run in a delta pipeline. I misunderstood.

Answer (score -1):

from the erorr message it seems, package `dlt` is not installed. Consider installing `dlt` package using below pip command.

```
pip install dlt
```

After installation, run below command to see is `dlt` package installed.

```python
pip list
```

This should solve the error.

Comment: This is wrong. That is a different package. DLT comes installed on the Databricks Runtimes